# Consulta SQL simples

Tags: sql-server, tsql, stored-procedures

Tenho uma proc que recebe o ID de um produto.
Se ela recebe NULL, então deve listar todos os produtos. Se recebe o ID específico, deve listar apenas aquele produto.

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem precisar criar uma consulta dinâmica?

Comment: Voce pode mudar a proc? Seria mais fácil se postasse o corpo dela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE (id = @varid OR @varid IS NULL)
```

Comment: Claro! É isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Só pra complementar a solução do amigo ai:
Você também pode usar a função `isnull`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = isnull(@varid, id)
```